# Explicit form of the foliation associated to a differential one-form

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm writing because of a problem in constructiong the foliation associated to a differential one-form.

Explicitely I have the following differential one-form $\theta$ on Minkowski spacetime $\mathcal{M}$:

$$
\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^{1})^{2}-(x^{0})^{2}}}\left(x^{1}dx^{0}-x^{0}dx^{1}\right)
$$
and I want to find the foliation associated to it.

The differential one-form $\theta$ is integrable, in the sense of Frobenius theorem, i.e. $\theta\wedge d\theta=0$.

I'm sorry but I can not provide any more insights because I'm not very confident with foliations.

In the concrete I want to find the explicit form of the leaves of the foliation.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to look at the vector fields annihilate by $\theta$.  It is easy to see that these are spanned by $x^0\partial_0 + x^1\partial_1$.  This is the radial vector field so the foliation is by lines through the origin.

Note: If you were talking about four-dimensional space (the foliation only cares about the underyling manifold so this is really just a question of $\mathbb R^4$ and not Minkowski space), then a leaf would just be the cartesian product of $\mathbb R^2$ with a line through the origin in (another copy of) $\mathbb R^2$.  Also, for $\theta$ to be well-defined you of course want to restrict to the open subset where $x^0 \ne \pm x^1$.

Comment: Thank You Eric O. Korman. For physical reasons I have to restrict myself to $(x^{1})^{2}\geq(x^{0})^{2}$. Why do you say the foliations is by lines through the origin? I guess You refer to the integral curves of $x^{0}\partial_{x^{0}} + x^{1}\partial_{x^{1}}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: Moreover what is the explicit expression of the leaves? I know I am being boring but this is the first time I work with foliations associated to differential forms that are not exact.

Comment: Correct, the leaves are the integral curves of $x^0\partial_0 + x^1\partial_1$.  So explicitly the leaves are parameterized by $x^0 = v^0 t, y^0 = v^1 t$, where $v^0,v^1$ are constants.

Comment: I think that the integral curves of the vector field are determined by the equations $\frac{dx^{0}(t)}{dt}=x^{0}(t)$ and $\frac{dx^{1}(t)}{dt}=x^{1}(t)$, thus I think that we have $x^{0}(t)=x^{0}_{0}\exp(t)$ and $x^{1}(t)=x^{1}_{0}\exp(t)$ where $x^{0}_{0}$ and $x^{1}_{0}$ are constants.

Comment: Your format for the integral curves is just a reparameterization of the format in the preceding comment by Eric. C. Korman. One thing to keep in mind about foliations is that their leaves are not assumed to come with any particular parameterization, their leaves are simply subsets of the phase space. Of course whenever you can express a leaf by solving a differential equation with initial conditions, as you just did, then that gives one particular parameterization of the leaf.

Comment: Right, I was being a little sloppy since integral curves usually mean a specific paramterization but for the foliation we just care about the image of the curve in the manifold (as per Lee's comment)

Comment: Thank you both. I understand the equivalence by reparametrization, however I can not see what explicitely the leaves are (as submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$).

Comment: The leaves are the submanifolds of the form $\{(x^0_0 \exp(t), x^1_0 \exp(t), x^2, x^3) \mid t, x^2,x^3 \in \mathbb R\}$ for some constants $x^0_0, x^1_0$.

Comment: Ok, that was a sort of trivial question. I really Thank You, now it is all clear to me. Thanks again for your disponibility.